# Where does Path.GetTempFileName(...) create files under XP?

Tags: .net, file, temp

Under Vista when you call [GetTempFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) files get created in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\

Does anyone know where they get created under XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends where the temporary folder is configured:

```
echo %TEMP%
```

Usually it is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value of environment variable %TEMP%. You can find that under My Computer - > Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables